# Why do I fail to install Maps on my mediawiki? and what should I do?

Tags: maps, mediawiki

[mediawiki version information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gUvK.png)
[official installation documentation](https://maps.extension.wiki/wiki/Installation)

[error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6uA6.png)
I figure out that I didn't have composer.local.json in my computer,but I have composer.local.json-sample under the directory of mediawiki.
What should I do next?

Comment: Create `composer.local.json`, obviously. Rename `composer.local.json-sample`, add `mediawiki/maps:~10.0` to it, run `composer update`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, it doesn't work. I figure out that my composer doesn't support "COMPOSER=composer.local.json". So I just ignore it and succeed.